# Retrofit nested Json response to string

Tags: android, retrofit

I have a nested json response from my api like this:

```
{
    "notif_title":"Generic Notification",
    "notif_message":"you have a message",
    "url":"https://www.google.com",
    "set_profile":{
                   "54fdc8eb77761b8844e65f96":"1"
                  }
}
```

***Problem***

The problem is that I want to get the set_profile json as a string no as an object because that object will be changing and I don't need to make any changes to it.

***Question***

Can I get that object as a string using retrofit?, thanks

Comment: And what exactly would you want to be the value of that string? The whole JSON object, including curly braces and all? Either way, you should be able to do that using a custom `TypeAdapterFactory`.

Comment: yes, including all. Will look at the TypeAdapterFactory option, thanks

Answer (score 1):

In retrofit if you want to parse JSON with dynamic keys (with dynamic names) you need to use HashMap for sure.

```
public class Name {
    @SerializedName("notif_title")
    @Expose
    private String notif_title;

    @SerializedName("notif_message")
    @Expose
    private String notif_message;

    @SerializedName("url")
    @Expose
    private String url;

    @SerializedName("set_profile")
    @Expose
    private Map<String, String> set_profile;
    //...setters and getters
}
```

hope this help